# Why do I have duplicates in my zsh history?

Tags: zsh, command-history

```
> zsh --version
zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)
```

```
> setopt
alwaystoend
autocd
autopushd
combiningchars
completeinword
correct
extendedhistory
noflowcontrol
histexpiredupsfirst
histignorealldups
histignorespace
histreduceblanks
histsavenodups
histverify
interactive
interactivecomments
login
longlistjobs
monitor
promptsubst
pushdignoredups
pushdminus
sharehistory
shinstdin
zle
> cat ~/.zsh_history
: 1595363811:0;ls 2&>1 /dev/null
: 1595363821:0;ls /dev/null
: 1595363831:0;cat ~/.zsh_history
: 1595363837:0;ls /dev/null
: 1595363841:0;setopt
: 1595363845:0;cat ~/.zsh_history
: 1595363993:0;setopt
: 1595364000:0;ls
: 1595364009:0;cat ~/.zsh_history
```

It is ignoring them if they are one after the other like `histignoredups` but AFAIK, my configuration should ignore any and all.

```bsh
> cat ~/.zshrc ~/.zshenv ~/.zprofile
# secrets-management -> master
###
#this file is generated edit ~/.config/yadm/alt/.gitconfig
##template instead
###

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/calebcushing/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="typewritten"
TYPEWRITTEN_CURSOR="block"
TYPEWRITTEN_RIGHT_PROMPT_PREFIX="# "
TYPEWRITTEN_GIT_RELATIVE_PATH=true


# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS=true

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

ZSH_COLORIZE_STYLE="monokai"

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
  colored-man-pages
  colorize
  command-not-found
  direnv
  history-substring-search
  gitfast
  git-auto-fetch
  git-escape-magic
  gitignore
  magic-enter
  safe-paste
  scd
  themes
  z
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

source $HOME/.config/my/rc.sh

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
export EDITOR='vim'
export VISUAL='vim'

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.


# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

alias vi="vim -Xp"
alias vim="vim -Xp"

jdk() {
  version=$1
  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v"$version");
  java -version
}

setopt CORRECT
setopt SHARE_HISTORY
setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS
unsetopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS

export LESS="-R --no-init --quit-if-one-screen"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
export HISTSIZE="1000"


eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"
```

Second question: Should I setopt in `~/.zshrc` or `~/.zshenv`?

Comment: Works for me (with zsh 5.4.2 and 5.8 but I doubt that it was a bug since no relevant fix appears in the changelog). Please share a full `.zshrc` that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' A default zsh reproduces the problem. Or simply do a `unsetopt $(setopt)` to clear all zsh options.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' added a `cat` of the `z` files

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only option needed to trim all duplicates is `histignorealldups`, and you have it already set, so yes, duplicates are being removed

> but **from memory**

And you are looking to the history stored in file (`cat $HISTFILE`).

#### how to reproduce

Start a new zsh instance, erase all history entries and execute some commands

```
% zsh -i
% a=( $(setopt) )
% unsetopt $a
% HISTSIZE=0
% HISTSIZE=99
% history
   95  HISTSIZE=99
% setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
% ls >/dev/null
% clear
% ls >/dev/null
% history
  113  HISTSIZE=99
  114  history
  115  setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
  116  ls >/dev/null
  117  clear
  118  ls >/dev/null
```

Now, you can set the option `histignorealldups` and all duplicates will disappear (from memory):

```
% setopt histignorealldups
% history
  113  HISTSIZE=99
  115  setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
  117  clear
  118  ls >/dev/null
  122  setopt histignorealldups
```

But that doesn't mean that the lines have been erased from the history file:

```
% cat ~/.histfile | tail -n 10
setopt INC_APPEND_HISTORY
ls >/dev/null
clear
ls >/dev/null
history
setopt histignorealldups
history
setopt histignorealldups
history
cat ~/.histfile | tail -n 10
```

To remove duplicates from the file you would have to edit the file.

I recommend you don't do that, as the history might be **shared** by several zsh instances running in parallel. This is not a trivial problem.

Comment: ah, so what you're saying is you can't actually deduplicate the file

Comment: well... through settings.

Comment: Yes, you can, by setting `HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS`. Just make sure you set `HISTSIZE` to a larger value than `SAVEHIST`. Otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Strange, using `setopt histignorealldups` *did* prune my existing `.zsh_history` file even though I had existing zsh sessions running. At least I *think* that's what happened; I didn't prune it by hand!

Answer (score 24):

Add the following lines to your `~/.zshrc` file to avoid duplicates in history

```
setopt HIST_EXPIRE_DUPS_FIRST
setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS
setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
setopt HIST_FIND_NO_DUPS
setopt HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS
```

Comment: This worked for me! To be more specific: edit the profile file with `nano ~/.zshrc`; then I only needed to add `setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS` and finally `source ~/.zhrc` to apply the changes